# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS dual boot with Windows 11 has graphics issues, freezes in Wayland without nomodeset

Tags: dual-boot, graphics

I have been trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11 on my laptop with a bootable USB drive and when I get to the install page, the screen crashes and freezes.

When I use the `nomodeset` parameter, this fixes the issues. I also switched from Wayland to Xorg and booted without nomodeset. Although this works, I am still having graphics and display issues. The screen keeps flickering every few minutes and it’s super annoying and distracting. I have tried everything, from `amdgpu-install` to updating the kernel, and still, nothing will prevent the inevitable screen flickering.

Here are my specs:

- Lenovo Thinkpad T14s Gen 4
- Graphics 32GB RAM
- 1920x1200 resolution 60Hz refresh rate
- 512GB SSD
- AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 7840u w/ AMD 780m

Could somebody help me fix this issue? I didn’t realise it was this difficult to dual boot Ubuntu and actually be able to use it. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Give Ubuntu 23.10 a try. Usually, recent versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware